# Using Azure Blob storage, how to I react in a custom way after a REQUEST TO an azure blob file?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

For example, I can see based on online documentation that I can respond to events such as a file getting uploaded or modified. But what about simply responding to a request that is made to the resource, such as a making a GET request to;
https://{storageName1}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName1}/LocationName1/{fileName1}.docx

I would like to be able to trigger some type of event and respond accordingly. I just need some hook into the request. I dont need to modify the request, just respond to instances where the GET request is made to the resource.

Comment: This not a supported scenario at the moment.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the bigger picture ? what is your use case ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to perform an action when a blob is accessed, you may be able to enable [Storage Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-logging-and-accessing-log-data) and monitor the `$logs` container to see the requests being made.

If you need to intercept the request then you can't do it directly, but if you can change the hostname that the clients use then you could route requests through [Azure Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) to an Azure Function that does the processing.

Comment: Problem with storage logging is that it can take up to an hour to have the log available in this scenario but yeah could work. also logs are stored in a $log container so it sounds possible to use eventgrid to send events when files inside the container has changed...